# Can't access uploaded files via Podio API

Tags: podio

We actually want to upload a file and attach it to an item but we're having problems just uploading it.

We are having a problem uploading an image into an item. We cant seem to access the image we uploaded to Podio via the API. We get a - **"Sorry, you don't have access to this file. You might want to ask your admin to provide you the access to this file."**

Which is so weird because everyone in our team cant access it, and we're admins on our workspaces. I also setup the api/secret keys and i'm and admin on that workspace. Whats wrong with this?

This is the code:

```
Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret);

try {

    Podio::authenticate_with_app($app_id, $app_token);

    $upload = PodioFile::upload('PATH_TO_FILE', 'test_image.jpg');

    if( $upload != ""){
        echo "<br><br>Image uploaded to podio!<br><br>";
        echo "<pre>".$upload."</pre>";
        echo "<br><br>".$upload->file_id."<br>";
        echo $upload->link."<br>";
    }

    if( PodioFile::attach( $upload->file_id, array('ref_type' => 'item', 'ref_id' => 43 )) != ""){
        echo "<br><br>Image attached to item!<br>";
    }

}catch (PodioError $e) {
    echo $e->body['error_description'];
}

Podio::set_debug(true);
```

Comment: Please share full error message with stack-trace. Can you please also explain why you are trying to attach to item_id `43` ?

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio this is a part of the return result of the upload item `[rights] => Array (
            [0] => update
            [1] => view
            [2] => delete
            [3] => download
        ) [created_by] => Array(
            [type] => app
            [id] => 20352724
            [avatar_type] => icon` 
but as said above we cant access the file in podio. we want to upload a file then attach it into an item in podio in this case item 43 was the item we want it attached to. "The app with id 20352724 does not have the right add_file on item with id 43" error log

Comment: So, here is what goes wrong: item_id `43` is **for sure** not your item :) You need to find and use item_id and not app_item_id

Comment: Btw, how did you get error "Sorry, you don't have access to this file. You might want to ask your admin to provide you the access to this file.". Is it coming from Podio API?

Comment: I get that, "Sorry, you dont have access.." when i access the podio file uploaded via the `$upload->link` so this is the main problem, we cant even access the uploaded file thats why when we attach it, it gives the - "The app with id 20352724 does not have the right add_file on item with id 43" error, there's nothing wrong with my setup, authentication, and upload code right? @Pavlo-Podio

Comment: You can't access file itself until it's linked to something because files don't have own access-control system. Once file is attached to item or task or workspace or whatever else, then you might be able to access it if you have enough rights :). There is at least one error that I've highlighted already, `item_id=43` is for sure not your item, so you can't attach file to it.

Comment: Ohhh interesting, thanks for pointing this out @Pavlo-Podio will check it out once i get back to work, will keep you posted,thanks!

Comment: @Pavlo-Podio you were right! It was a wrong item ID, thank you so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access file itself until it's linked to something because files don't have own access-control system. Once file is attached to item or task or workspace or whatever else, then you might be able to access it if you have enough rights :).

There is at least one error **item_id=43** is for sure not your item, so you can't attach file to it.

Comment: Thanks Pavlo, definitely wrong item id, got it working now, thanks!